# looking for a fast growing Leucaena leucocephala seeds

Tags: seeds, growth

I am looking for a fast growing Leucaena leucocephala seeds. Now, I am cultivating Leucaena leucocephala which can grow 6.00 Meters in a year. But I am looking for a genetically improved seeds which can grow upto 10.00 Meters in a year.

If any one the best verity of seeds, please post your answer

Comment: I think questions about where to buy seeds are outside the scope of this forum as the information becomes out of date quickly.

Comment: Kevinsky's right, This would fall under the category of shopping questions, which tend to become obsolete way too fast to be useful on this site (see [Teaching a man to fish, garden, and … shop.](http://meta.gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/285/teaching-a-man-to-fish-garden-and-shop), on meta). Now, if you changed the question to ask for the name of a specific variety, rather than for a source, your question will be on topic here. For more info on what topics we cover, please refer to the [Help Center](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: So you are actually looking for 'GMO' seed?  Genetically Modified Seed has not been proven beneficial in any category.  In fact the facts show huge toxicity, carcinogenic and even more vulnerability with disease and insects (in the longer term).

Comment: @stormy - doesn't have to be GMO, can just be a new hybrid produced by standard crossing experiments.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware, there are no new hybrid varieties of this plant available - unless some breeder is busy crossing varieties or generally tinkering to try to produce one with  increased growth rates, there's nothing currently available. It's not impossible that someone somewhere is trying though, there's been a fair amount of research into this Genus in the last few years, and this particular variety is widely used for timber, but as to who might be doing that, no idea.